# CentOS6 Backup fails; "permission denied"

Tags: linux, bash, backup, permissions, postgresql

I am currently trying to do a backup of a server and am getting an error message when running my script. The script runs correctly on certain directories, but for the directory I am attempting to use I get the error message "permission denied", even with proper access.

For example, when trying to create the backup in the /var/... directory using my script, it works.
However, if I attempt to run the script in the /opt/app/backup directory I am not able to:
[image: Permission denied]

I also have the correct read/write access for the directory, compare /var and /opt:
[image: Access comparison of var and opt]

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved the problem!

When I looked a little deeper into the actual access I had, it was only of degree 755:
Only the **owner** had write access to the directory!

To fix the problem, I simply did `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt` and this allowed the script to write to the directory. Once the backup script ran, I changed the permissions back to their default state.